# pynaoqi-python2.7-naoqi

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i am studying mechatronic/robotics and I have to include Nao in Linux Ubuntu 10.04 fuerte 32bit. The napqi on Nap does not work because Nao is very old. He works with NaoQiAcademics-1.2.0-Linux. I think I need the pynaoqi-python2.7-naoqi that I can work with Nao in ROS fuerte? But I cannot actually download this from aldebaran site because they offert only new versions of naoqi. Can someone of you sent me a link for downloading this pynaoqi? thanks a lot for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167411/pynaoqi-python2.7-naoqi/) by [Tajana](https://answers.ros.org/users/18206/tajana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2014-05-23**:
what version of the robot do you have ? Aldebaran does not support such an old NAOqi anymore. You can't upgrade to 1.14 ?

**Comment by [Tajana](https://answers.ros.org/users/18206/tajana/) on 2014-05-26**:
I do not know what version. I have allready talked to aldebaran and they had told me that it is not possible to upgrade my Nao because of his age.
But I hopped that someone who also worked with older ones can give me a pynaoqi
for an old version of Nao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

With a bit of archaeology, I checked how it was done in NAOqi 1.2.

In your SDK, or on your robot, you should find a path similar to: extern/python/aldebaran/
In there you'll find naoqi.py, inaoqi.py and _inaoqi.so
If I remember correctly you need to add the path to naoqi.py to your environment.

If you can't find these, please contact us via Vincent ( above ) and we can get this to you.

If all else fails, you can use urls similar to http://ROBOT:9559/?eval=MODULENAME.METHODNAME(args like python)

Hope this helps,

Chris

---

Originally posted by [ChrisKilner](https://answers.ros.org/users/18531/chriskilner/) with karma: 16 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tajana](https://answers.ros.org/users/18206/tajana/) on 2014-06-02**:
Thanks a lot for your help. I could found this naoqi.py on my Nao but there`s the next Problem. How can I set this path of naoqi.py to my Environment? root@nao /opt/naoqi/extern/python/Aldebaran ---> inside of this ther is naoqi.py i work in ubuntu@ubuntu. And I can`t find this when I am working there.
Tajana

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, I just found that you can get old NAOqi's versions here:
http://robocup.bowdoin.edu/public/software/nao/NaoQi/

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1